# Why re-throwing error in catch block having TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I have a route handler in express.js and inside it, I am calling an asynchronous function which should return me some value. I am using bluebird promises to handle the promises. Below is a sample code.

```
router.js
---------
router.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
 return Promise.try(() => serviceFile.validate())
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Response: ', response);   
})
        .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error: ', error) // TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Promise]
})

})


serviceFile.js
--------------
async function validate() {
  return Promise.try(() => axios.post('/endpoint'))
         .then((response) => response.data)
         .catch((error) => {
         console.log('Error: ', error.response.data) // successfully printing the error data object
          throw error; 
}) 
}
```

When I call the `validate()` in the `Service.js` file, it fails the request (which I want) and successfully prints the error. But I don't want to handle the error here, so I re-throw it and expects to handle it in the `router.js` file. But in the `router.js` file, I am getting `error` as `undefined` and it says, `TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Promise]`

I am not getting any clue where I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an `async` function there. Try writing it without the `Promise` and instead just `await` everything. At the very least it will be cleaner. `try { const res = await axios.post("/endpoint"); return res.data; } catch (e) { console.log(e.response.data); throw e; }`

Comment: That said the answer seems pretty clear from the error. You are returning a Promise (the calls to validate, etc) where a function is expected. Somewhere (I'm not sure where, I don't know express) you likely need `return function () { /* something here */ }` or something similar (ie. returning a *new* arrow function)

Comment: Your usage of `Promise.try` appears superfluous. Why are you calling that at all?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error message? That should give you some hint what code was expecting a function

Answer (score 0):

its sort of unclear what serviceFile.validate does unless thats the second function you listed, this might be a more clear way of using promises

```js
router.post('/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await serviceFile.validate()
    console.log('Response: ', response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', error)
  }
})

function validate () {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/endpoint')
      resolve(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response && err.response.data) {
        reject(err.response.data)
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: i would suggest adding your version of the answer in response to the OP's question then highlighting how its supposed to be written. The code above in my answer **will work** the code in your linked example from what the OP said **will not work**

Comment: OP hasn't done (or shared) enough debugging yet to tell what doesn't work and why, but that doesn't change that the code in your answer is a bad practice.